# Kubelet periodically lose TCP connection with pods when doing liveness/readiness probe check on GKE

Tags: kubernetes

We have an software system deployed in a single GKE(google kubernetes engine) cluster node which using around 100 pods, in each pod we defined TCP readiness probe, now we could see the readiness probe periodically fails with `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` on different pods.

With the tcpdump traces on the cluster node and the failing pods, we find that the packets sent from the cluster node seems right, while the pod doesn't receive the TCP packet, but failing pod could still receive IP broadcast packets.

The weird thing is if we ping/curl/wget the cluster node from the failing pod, regardless the cluster node has http service or not, the TCP connection will be recovered immediately and the readiness check will become fine.

An example is as below:

The cluster node host: 10.44.0.1
The failing pod host: 10.44.0.92

**tcpdump on cbr0 interface of the cluster node**:

```
#sudo tcpdump -i cbr0  host 10.44.0.92

tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on cbr0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
17:33:52.913052 ARP, Request who-has 10.44.0.1 tell 10.44.0.92, length 28
17:33:52.913181 ARP, Reply 10.44.0.1 is-at 0a:58:0a:2c:00:01 (oui Unknown), length 28
17:33:57.727497 IP 10.44.0.1.47736 > 10.44.0.92.mysql: Flags [S], seq 756717730, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 1084890021 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:33:57.727537 IP 10.44.0.92.mysql > 10.44.0.1.47736: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 756717731, win 0, length 0
17:34:07.727563 IP 10.44.0.1.48202 > 10.44.0.92.mysql: Flags [S], seq 2235831098, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 1084900021 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:34:07.727618 IP 10.44.0.92.mysql > 10.44.0.1.48202: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2235831099, win 0, length 0
17:34:12.881059 ARP, Request who-has 10.44.0.92 tell 10.44.0.1, length 28
17:34:12.881176 ARP, Reply 10.44.0.92 is-at 0a:58:0a:2c:00:5c (oui Unknown), length 28
```

These are readiness checks packets sent from Kubelet, we could see the failing node responds with `Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 756717731, win 0, length 0` which is a TCP handshake ACK/SYN reply, it is a failing packet and the TCP connection will NOT be established.

The if we `exec -it` to the failing pod and ping the cluster node from the pod as below:

```
root@mariadb:/# ping 10.44.0.1
PING 10.44.0.1 (10.44.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.44.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=3.301 ms
64 bytes from 10.44.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.303 ms
```

Then let's see what's happening on cluster node side from the TCP dump:

```
#sudo tcpdump -i cbr0  host 10.44.0.92

17:34:17.728039 IP 10.44.0.92.mysql > 10.44.0.1.48704: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2086181490, win 0, length 0
17:34:27.727638 IP 10.44.0.1.49202 > 10.44.0.92.mysql: Flags [S], seq 1769056007, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 1084920022 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:34:27.727693 IP 10.44.0.92.mysql > 10.44.0.1.49202: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1769056008, win 0, length 0
17:34:34.016995 ARP, Request who-has 10.44.0.1 tell 10.44.0.92, length 28
17:34:34.018358 ARP, Reply 10.44.0.1 is-at 0a:58:0a:2c:00:01 (oui Unknown), length 28
17:34:34.020020 IP 10.44.0.92 > 10.44.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 53, seq 0, length 64
17:34:34.020101 IP 10.44.0.1 > 10.44.0.92: ICMP echo reply, id 53, seq 0, length 64
17:34:35.017197 IP 10.44.0.92 > 10.44.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 53, seq 1, length 64
17:34:35.017256 IP 10.44.0.1 > 10.44.0.92: ICMP echo reply, id 53, seq 1, length 64
17:34:36.018589 IP 10.44.0.92 > 10.44.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 53, seq 2, length 64
17:34:36.018700 IP 10.44.0.1 > 10.44.0.92: ICMP echo reply, id 53, seq 2, length 64
17:34:37.019791 IP 10.44.0.92 > 10.44.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 53, seq 3, length 64
17:34:37.019837 IP 10.44.0.1 > 10.44.0.92: ICMP echo reply, id 53, seq 3, length 64
17:34:37.730849 IP 10.44.0.1.49666 > 10.44.0.92.mysql: Flags [S], seq 1304758051, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 1084930025 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:34:37.730900 IP 10.44.0.92.mysql > 10.44.0.1.49666: Flags [S.], seq 1267340310, ack 1304758052, win 28160, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 3617117819 ecr 1084930025,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:34:37.730952 IP 10.44.0.1.49666 > 10.44.0.92.mysql: Flags [.], ack 1, win 222, options [nop,nop,TS val 1084930025 ecr 3617117819], length 0
17:34:37.731149 IP 10.44.0.1.49666 > 10.44.0.92.mysql: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 222, options [nop,nop,TS val 1084930025 ecr 3617117819], length 0
17:34:37.731268 IP 10.44.0.92.mysql > 10.44.0.1.49666: Flags [P.], seq 1:107, ack 2, win 220, options [nop,nop,TS val 3617117819 ecr 1084930025], length 106
17:34:37.731322 IP 10.44.0.1.49666 > 10.44.0.92.mysql: Flags [R], seq 1304758053, win 0, length 0
17:34:47.728119 IP 10.44.0.1.50138 > 10.44.0.92.mysql: Flags [S], seq 502800802, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 1084940022 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:34:47.728179 IP 10.44.0.92.mysql > 10.44.0.1.50138: Flags [S.], seq 4294752326, ack 502800803, win 28160, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 3617127816 ecr 1084940022,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

We could see the ICMP packets are the packets for the ping command sent from the pod, after the ICMP packets, the readiness check packets now immediately become right, the TCP handleshake success.

Not only ping could make it work, other commands like curl/wget could also make it work, just need to reach the cluster node from the failing pod, after that, the TCP connection from cluster node to the pod will become correct.

The failing pods change time to time, it could happen to any pod, since there are 100 pods up running on the node, not sure if it triggers certain system limitation, however all others work correctly, we don't see huge CPU utilization, and there still be few GB memory left on the node.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Did you check system log of unalienable PODs for any errors, e.g., contrack errors? Could you provide it? `kubectl log <POD-NAME>`

Comment: @qingsong Li, did you manage to get to the bottom of this or find a workaround? Hitting something similar on GKE ourselves.